# Reference routes and Web API

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-web-api

I'm having some problem regarding some routes. First of all, see this post:
[REST api, POST entity with relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341788/rest-api-post-entity-with-relationships)

I'm not sure of how to actually create the route/routes for that answer so I started doing this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        //Artist/////////////////////////////
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ArtistAlbum",
            routeTemplate: "api/artist/{id}/album",
            defaults: new { controller = "ArtistAlbum" }
        );
        ////////////////////////////////////
```

But the first route would also make it possible to post, get and so on by simply navigating to `/api/ArtistAlbum/{artistid}/album` which isn't quite what I'm looking for.

I want to limit the user to only be able to get,post,put,delete etc by using the `/api/artist/{id}/album` route. Any ideas?

Any suggestions of how to do this since creating a lot of routes manually doesn't seem very nice if you ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order matters here. If you want `api/artist/{id}/album` to take precedence over something like `api/artist/{id}`, then you need to switch the order of your calls to `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute`

This way the `api/artist` route will take precedence over `api/ANYTHING`.

Comment: Yeah.. I keep forgetting this, thanks :)
But what if the "client" would make a post against /api/ArtistAlbum.. I dont want that to be possible.. since I want to force the client to use the other route (api/artist/{id}/album).. or am I missing something here??

Comment: Why not let them? But, you can use `config.Routes.IgnoreRoute("api/ArtistAlbum/*");` I believe that will work, but the * syntax might be off. It might have to be `{*}`

Comment: Aha ok thanks, thats great :)
The only reason for why is that I only want one way to create the album to prevent confusion.. and I also dont want the ArtistAlbum-controller to be "directly" accessable by the {controller}/{action}/{id} route.. but well.. thats more a matter of personal "taste" of how to structure the api I guess :)