# How to POST entity with relationships in REST endpoint - Kotlin Spring Data

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I followed [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/) to create a basic web app in Kotlin using Spring Boot. However, I fail to POST new entities with a many-to-one relationship to an existing resource.

My code:

```
@Entity
class Song(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long? = null,
    var title: String,
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    var addedBy: User)

@Entity
class User(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long? = null,
    var email: String,
    var displayName: String)
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/songs")
class SongController(private val repository: SongRepository) {

    @PostMapping("/")
    fun add(@RequestBody song: Song) =
        repository.save(song)
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28081855/6460275) and others point out that you can reference another resource using its URI, but sending the following request:

```
{
  "title": "Some title",
  "addedBy": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/1"
}
```

gets me an errors with stack trace `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of 'com.example.springboot.User' (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('http://localhost:8080/api/users/1'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of 'com.example.springboot.User' (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('http://localhost:8080/api/users/1')\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 6, column: 13] (through reference chain: com.example.springboot.Song[\"addedBy\"])`

I got out of this that somewhere between Jackson/Hibernate/Spring Data it fails to convert the User resource URI into a User entity, but I'm in the dark where this magic should happen.

It seems to be an issue that occurs with Kotlin specifically. All the suggestions here on SO do not solve this specific error and the tutorial itself stops just short of dealing with relationships. If it's not the right approach at all to handle relationships this way I'd be eager to know what the preferred practice would be.

Comment: What exactly do you post as body to the endpoint? The exception already tells you what’s wrong. The Song object eg the addedBy property can not be deserialised based on only the provided string. You need at least a sub object json representation of the user
 Further you shoul not directly post entities to the controller. Use value objects and then map them to entities. So you need to create an instance  of Song. Based on the added by you need to get the corresponding user entity and add this entity to the song. You can also only provide only the user Id and then so the Mapping.

Comment: @Daniel I'm sending the request body as stated above (3rd code block) or do you mean something else? Sending entities directly without having to use value objects is exactly what the Spring tutorial does, and also referencing other entities by using the resource URI should work OOB with Spring, right? See also what they do here but with PUT instead https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships

Comment: Hey Steven, the tutorial is using HATEOAS. See the request body where they are referencing the corresponding child entity by using `"books" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/authors/1/books"
    }` Meaning you should also apply this pattern to your request. Otherwise this will not work. HATEOAS allows you to directly reference the related child entities by their corresponding resource path but you need to keep the necessary structure which your posted request body is missing.

Comment: Thanks @DanielWosch, it seems that I've been picking up examples that work as I mentioned in my question which are in fact using Spring Data REST (which I am not), I guess that's where my confusion comes from. Spring Data REST seem to follow HATEOAS indeed, I will try using that in my project. Thanks again!

Comment: What you could do when using "normal" REST is to just provide the ID (1) in added by. In your controller / service you can fetch the corresponding user and then add it to your target entity.

Comment: @DanielWosch that works! Although I had to make the remaining attributes of the User entity nullable, not sure if that is recommended?

Comment: Sorry, can't follow you with this one. Why do you need to set the attributes to Nullable? For my understanding the User with ID 1 already exists. So you just need to fetch it first, assign it to the new Song entity and that's it :)

Comment: I have posted a corresponding answer to your question so you can accept it ;)

Comment: @DanielWosch I guess I must have misunderstood you, I thought you meant posting something like { ..., "addedBy": { "id": 1 }}, in which case it deserialises a User entity, but then it will fail if the other properties are not nullable. I think you meant rewriting the entity so that it addedBy is the id value directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial is using `HATEOAS`. See the request body where they are referencing the corresponding child entity by using

```
"books" : {       "href" : "http://localhost:8080/authors/1/books"     }
```

Meaning you should also apply this pattern to your request. Otherwise this will not work. HATEOAS allows you to directly reference the related child entities by their corresponding resource path but you need to keep the necessary structure which your posted request body is missing. Further you must support HATEOAS in your WebService / WebApi / Spring Boot Project.

What you could do:

```
{
  "title": "Some title",
  "addedByUserId": "1"
}
```

Then

```
@PostMapping("/")
    fun add(@RequestBody song: Song) =
        val userEntity = userRepository.findById(song.getAddedByUserId())
        Song newSong = new SongEntity();
        // map props
        newSong.setUser(userEntity)
        repository.save(song)
```

That code does not work but I hope you get the idea.

**Further**

In your code you are treating the Request Body as an Entity. Please consider to separate your incoming Class and your Entity class. This would make several things easier.

Comment: Supporting HATEOAS by using Spring Data REST was the key to make it work. For POSTing an antity with a many-to-one relationship I can now use {  "title": "Some title",  "addedBy": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/1" }. Thanks!

Comment: A question regarding your last remark: isn't Spring Data REST promoting bad practices by letting you directly posting and retrieving entities when it would be preferred to use intermediate objects?

Comment: It depends: With auto of the box HATEOAS there seems to be not other way than directly using the relation to the real entity. But to be honest: I am not familiar with HATEOAS in practice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing jackson's kotlin module, it's exactly what it was created for.

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin

Just adding this dependency in your project will cause spring to autoconfigure your object mapper with this new module. If you have a Bean with your own created objectMapper then you need to configure it manually, there's a section about this in module's `README.md`

Comment: Thanks Yayotrón, I had this dependency already loaded, but it doesn't seem to make any difference. However, it seems that this format of posting relationships isn't supported in Spring Boot out-of-the-box, and examples that I've found online seem to be working with Spring Data REST specifically. I'm going to find out how to get that working within my project.